# ObjectDisposedException when using Multiple Asynchronous Clients to Multiple Servers

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I've been looking into the [Asynchronous Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx) and [Asynchronous Server Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx) examples on MSDN and have happily punched up the example that works flawlessly when one Client connects to one Server.  My problem is that I need to synchronise a chunk of work with a number of machines so they execute at about the same time (like millisecond difference).  The action is reasonably simple, talk to the child servers (all running on the same machine but on different ports for initial testing), simulate its processing and send a 'Ready' signal back to the caller.  Once all the Servers have returned this flag (or a time-out occurs), a second message to is passed from the client to the acknowledged servers telling them to execute.

My approach so far has been to create two client instances, stored within a list, and start the routine by looping through the list.  This works well but not particularly fast as each client's routine is ran synchronously.  To speed up the process, I created a new thread and executed the routine on that for each client.  Now this does work allowing two or more servers to return back and synchronise appropriately.  Unfortunately, this is very error prone and the code errors with the 'ObjectDisposedException' exception on the following line of the 'ReceiveCallback' method...

```
// Read data from the remote device.
int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);
```

With some investigation and debugging I tracked the sockets being passed to the routine (using its handle) and found while it isn't connected, it is always the second socket to return that fails and not the first that does successfully read its response.  In addition, these socket instances (based upon the handle value) appear to be separate instances, but somehow the second (and subsequent responses) continue to error out on this line.

What is causing these sockets to inappropriately dispose of themselves before being legitmately processed?  As they are running in separate threads and there are no shared routines, is the first socket being inappropriately used on the other instances?  Tbh, I feel a bit lost at sea and while I could band-aid up these errors, the reliability of the code and potentially losing returning acknowledgements is not a favourable goal.  Any pointers?

Kind regards

Comment: OK - nailed it.  But I'm not entirely sure I have a 100% airtight explanation but I resolved the error by ensuring the methods were no longer static as well as the ManualResetEvent flag.  Tbh I thought that the socket code would access the methods anonymously and the 'private' keyword would ensure the scope - somehow this wasn't the case.

Anyhoo - resolved it, if somewhat perplexed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the shared / static ManualResetEvent was being set across the different instances so thread 1 would set the ManualResetEvent disposing the socket on the second thread.  By ensuring that no methods / properties were shared / static - each thread and socket would execute under its own scope.